# typescript mapping type does not fit

Tags: typescript

```
type A = { a: number, b: null } | { a: null, b: number };

const aaa: A[] = [{ a: 1, b: null }, { a: null, b: 1 }];


function ccc(props: A) {

}

aaa.map(temp => {
    ccc({ a: temp.a, b: temp.b }) // it comes error
})
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigM1wBtqoBfKAH2TSp1vMu3yOIYDcAKCEBjAPZYAzsDSoMsANoBdBFEUoFARi7taDcpr3VdULQ2XCRAMxxZRwAJaSootwAowxcWCmYYAJTIIvQi8qgAdHioYO7AEHhgCAB8wVDprh5GUPGJEaimuWARBAwBQvQBQA

How can I using like this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the original object to `ccc` works, as does spreading it into a new object.

```
ccc(temp)
```

```
ccc({ ...temp })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Unions Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) properly can rectify this error, change your type A

**from**

type A = { a: number, b: null } | { a: null, b: number };

**to**

type A = { a: number | null, b: null | number };

```
type A = { a: number | null, b: null | number };

const aaa: A[] = [{ a: 1, b: null }, { a: null, b: 1 }];

function ccc(props: A) {

}

aaa.map(temp => {
    ccc({ a: temp.a, b: temp.b })
})
```

Comment: Sorry for not enough information.
I want to when 'a' number 'b' must to be null and inverse situation.
but thank you for answering me!